# flatten nested data structure in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe:

```
 df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+
|             address|         coordinates|  id|latitude|longitude|                name|position|                json|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+
|Balfour St / Brun...|[-27.463431, 15.352472|79.0|    null|     null|79 - BALFOUR ST /...|    null|[-27.463431, 153.041031]|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+
```

I want to flatten the json column. 
I did :

```
val jsonSchema  = StructType(Seq(
StructField("latitude", DoubleType, nullable = true),
StructField("longitude", DoubleType, nullable = true)))

val a = df.select(from_json(col("json"), jsonSchema) as "content")
```

but

```
a.show() gives me :
+-------+
|content|
+-------+
|   null|
+-------+
```

Any idea how to parse json col properly and get content col in second dataframe (a) not null ?

Raw data is presented as :

```
{
    "id": 79,
    "name": "79 - BALFOUR ST / BRUNSWICK ST",
    "address": "Balfour St / Brunswick St",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": -27.463431,
      "longitude": 153.041031
    }
  }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your JSON column value is not clear. can you share a sample JSON  value and the expected output ? this will be helpful

Comment: @BalajiReddy done please check again

Comment: Can you share the schema of df ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your schema. You are trying to access a nested collection values like a regular value. I made changes to your schema and it worked for me.

```
val df = spark.createDataset(
  """
    |{
    |    "id": 79,
    |    "name": "79 - BALFOUR ST / BRUNSWICK ST",
    |    "address": "Balfour St / Brunswick St",
    |    "coordinates": {
    |      "latitude": -27.463431,
    |      "longitude": 153.041031
    |    }
    |  }
  """.stripMargin :: Nil)

val jsonSchema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true),

  StructField("coordinates",
    StructType(Seq(
      StructField("latitude", DoubleType, true)
      ,
      StructField("longitude", DoubleType, true)

    )), true)

)

)
val a = df.select(from_json(col("value"), jsonSchema) as "content")

a.show(false)
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|content                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|[79 - BALFOUR ST / BRUNSWICK ST,[-27.463431,153.041031]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```